# Is there a way to get the associated view row on change in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

CouchDB's [changes API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html#view) provides subscription to the changes on a view:

```
curl http://example.com/mydb/_changes?filter=_view&view=my/greatView
```

This returns a respond in two ways:

1. Simple: Returns `id`, `rev` and `seq` parameters on a change
2. `include_docs`: Includes involving doc to the response

Both of the options does not include the associated view row, eg:

```
{
  id: 'someid',
  key: ["some", "complex", "key"],
  value: {
    some: "value"
  }
}
```

How can I get the associated view row when I subscribed the changes on that view?

Answer (score 0):

You can't

According to the documentation, the view act as a filter, not as a view. It won't emit the keys.

See docs : http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/database/changes.html#changes-filter-view